# Validating result of JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (think "try parse") using JSON.Net

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, json.net

I have incoming messages that I need to try and parse in my own objects structure. SOme of these are well formed JSON obejcts and some are just nonsense.

I use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(incmoingString);` to do this. This however sometimes gives me a exception when the incoming is total garbage. Other times I get a non-complete object structure when the incoming string is kind of OK - and finally it sometimes work.

I've wrapped the conversion in a try/catch and than manually validate that I've gotten the properties I need to the deserialized result.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Probably not, unless the 'converter' allows you attach events like the `XmlSerializer` for unresolved entities/attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Json.NET supports [JSON Schema](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/01/04/json-net-3-5-beta-2-json-schema-validation.aspx). You could create a schema with all the required properties marked and validate incoming JSON against it before deserializing.

Comment: How would you do this?

Comment: Is there no way to just validate that the schema is valid JSON?