# How to validate schema during deserialization?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have custom converters for a couple of classes in a project, and I'd like to validate their schemas as part of deserialization.

This feels like it should be pretty straight forward, but I can't find it in the docs.

I could simply validate against the schema in the first part of `ReadJson`, or use `JsonValidatingReader`, but it seems like it should be part of the Converter itself, or otherwise explicitly part of the API rather than a case of "glue it together yourself".

I saw some mention of `JsonContract` in the source, but it's not clear if that's what I need, and searching Google for it just leads to a bunch of results for `JsonContractResolver`. (I'm not really clear on what that does or why I'd need it either.) If it's in the docs, I can't find it.

I found this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690189/validating-result-of-jsonconvert-deserializeobject-think-try-parse-using-jso#answer-2695965) which says "hey you can do this" but of course doesn't actually say how.

Has anyone done this? Do I just do it manually?

**Edit** to clarify: I know how to validate, and I know to deserialize. I want to do them together.

Answer (score 1):

The link provided in the answer to that question shows how to validate against a schema. Here's the sample code.

```
JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(schemaJson);

JObject person = JObject.Parse(@"{
  ""name"": ""James"",
  ""hobbies"": ["".NET"", ""Blogging"", ""Reading"", ""Xbox"", ""LOLCATS""]
}");

bool valid = person.IsValid(schema);
// true
```

Comment: That is specifically not what I'm asking. I know how to validate input against a schema. What I want to know is how to validate input against a schema *as part of the deserialization process*.

Comment: @recf Well, they're two separate things. Validate it. If it's valid, then deserialize it. If it's not valid, handle it.

Comment: So the answer is no, there is not a part of the API that treats it as part the same step. Got it. My intent was was to have a validation check prior inside the deserialization code, but before doing the actual deserialization in order to provide nice error messages, rather than get a generic InvalidFormatException or simply create the object in an invalid state.

Comment: You could create your own method (or extension method) that verifies and then deserializes if it's valid. If it fails validation, you can then create your own error message. Code is all about combining multiple steps into one step. So this would be a decent approach.

Comment: Yeah. What I will probably end up doing is writing a subclass of JsonConverter that validates first.